# Nextjs / prisma : can I manually name the many to many tables?

Tags: postgresql, next.js, prisma

By default Prisma names the many to many tables as follow: "_" + name of Table A + "to" + name of Table B ( which would give the name _TableaToTableb )

The name of the id fields inside those tables are "A" and "B" by default

Here are my two questions:

- is it possible to manually name the relation tables and the fields?
  I did not find any reference in the documentation about it but I am not yet very familiar with it yet ( checked [here](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations) )
- Is it a good idea to manually set the name of the relations?
  Apart from the very obvious issue of having possible name conflicts when doing so is there possible issues I am not foreseeing when wanting to set the names myself? ( harder to query? harder to use? ... )

The current stack is NextJs / postgreSQL / Prisma if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- No it's not possible to manually name the relation tables and fields.
- Why would you want to directly query the relation table? If you need extra metadata to be stored in the relation table, best to create an [implicit many-to-many relation](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/many-to-many-relations#explicit-many-to-many-relations).

Comment: Personally I am very I am very happy to use Prisma as it is, the client however is discovering Prisma and is not yet familiar with it's strengths and thus wants to use the tools they already have on the back end to do the queries and so on. This pretty much cripples most of the new tools but I have no say there ^^'